# Multiple copies of apps - where have they all come from and how do I remove the ones I don't want?

Tags: apt, software-installation, snap

I've just installed Ubuntu 19.10, and I found two icons of GIMP. As I didn't know snap, I deleted one of the packages installed via `apt-get install`. However, it drove me crazy and I searched my whole system for that other copy - and found it in the snap repository. So then I googled about snap and how to remove snap-packages and thought I'd be prepared, once I later found two copies of VLC media player.

BUT: While the "first" VLC-app. could be deleted via `apt-get remove vlc`, snap tells me it doesn't have that package, hence, the "second" VLC is still there. So, to check that I hadn't misspelled or overlooked something, I installed VLC via `snap install vlc` & `apt-get install vlc`. Now, I have three copies of VLC...

Is there a third way to install applications I don't know about? If I click right on the "additional" VLC-icon and click "show details", it only says

> unable to find vlc.desktop

Thank you in advance for your help!

---

**EDIT**
I've again searched my hard drive for the repository of the application and found it in `/usr/share`. Once I'd deleted the "VLC"-folder and restarted the computer, the icon disappeared from the Applications menu. However, I'd still like to know how to delete such applications "correctly", so I'm leaving the question open, in case someone can explain.

Comment: Personally I don't use `snap` versions and only `apt-get` versions. The big question is which do you prefer to use? Then seek help with removing the other versions.

Comment: There are MANY ways to install applications: Flatpaks, AppImages, Pips, Wheels, tarballs, and more. `apt` only keeps track of debs. `snap` only keeps track of snaps. It's the human's role to keep track of the different methods used and to prevent conflicts and duplicates.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: I don't prefer any, and I've tried to remove it in both ways

Comment: @user535733: Well, as I said I've just set up this new Ubuntu version a few days ago and I definitely have not installed VLC manually... guess it was already installed? I'll test different removing-options for the different ways then!

Comment: One method of troubleshooting is to uninstall the deb and snap versions, then use `which` and `find` to locate the remaining. Where something is installed in the filesystem is a good clue toward what method was used to install it.

Comment: In Ubuntu 19.10, apt get is starting to install snaps in some cases. You may use a command such as "find / -name '*.desktop' -exec grep -H "$1" {} \; 2>/dev/null" (replace $1 by the program label like you see it in the menu) to find any .desktop file for the app. The Exec= line will show where the executable is located. - yep, user535733 was slightly faster.

Comment: @user535733, yeah, I've just found where it is installed (see the edit of my question)

Comment: @Sven snaps are relatively new and you should study a little bit the difference between them and old fashioned `apt`. Then you can decide which platform is better for you.

Comment: `/usr/chare/vlc/*` files are provided by the `vlc-data` deb package. Some skin packages also place there. Perhaps your removal of deb-based VLC was incomplete? Did you remember to also remove all orphaned dependencies?

Comment: @user535733, I did not, thanks for that information!